# How to configure QEMU DHCP and DNS for VMs?

Tags: domain-name-system, dhcp, qemu

I am trying to configure a QEMU setup with several VMs that talk to each other (e.g. a LDAP server on a VM that provides SSH authentication to other internal VMs).

All these VMs are user mode and connected via `-net socket` and all of them have a virtual MAC address. No contact with the external world save for an open SSH port (`hostfwd`).

My question is: is it possible to configure the *internal* DHCP server (the one made available by QEMU) to supply IPs and names to the machines? Also and **simultaneously**, is there any way for the *internal* DNS resolver to supply lookups for these DHCP names?

I am aware of the `hostname` option on `-net user`, but that only solves part of the problem (nothing appears on the DNS server).

For example, if VM 1 has a `hostname=ldap`, the internal DNS server will not provide a resolution for that (`nslookup ldap` will have no results).

Thanks